# MS Access keeps changing my SQL which it then can't read

Tags: sql, ms-access

Good morning / afternoon,

I have a very simple MS Access DB and I have a query that works fine until MS Access gets it's hands on it and makes it more "readable", which it then can't read.  This is the query:

```
SELECT Checkout.*
FROM Checkout, (SELECT seatNumber, MAX(dateOut) AS lastOut FROM Checkout GROUP BY seatNumber) AS resultTable
WHERE Checkout.seatNumber=resultTable.seatNumber And resultTable.lastOut=Checkout.dateOut;
```

And this is what Access mangles it into:

```
SELECT Checkout.*
FROM Checkout, [SELECT seatNumber, MAX(dateOut) AS lastOut FROM Checkout GROUP BY seatNumber; ] AS resultTable
WHERE Checkout.seatNumber=resultTable.seatNumber And resultTable.lastOut=Checkout.dateOut;
```

And then carries on that it can't find the table.

I know there is no (easy) way to stop MS Access from being so helpful, but I was wondering if anyone can help me with a rework of the query.  I kind of get set in a way of doing things and then when that doesn't work it's hard to break out of it.  I was hoping a fresh and probably greatly more experienced eye than mine would be able to help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried building & editing the query graphically in MS Access?  Editing the SQL of MS Access has some risks, as you seem to have found. The graphical approach is a bit tedious as you will probably have to create the query of "summary" type  as an independent query resultTable, then join it to table Checkout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally encapsulate the logic of internal tables like resultTable as a separate VIEW (QUERY in MS Access parlance).  If you do that, you should be able to refer to it without problem in your query.

You can also write this kind of query as

```
SELECT * FROM Checkout C1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CheckOut C2 
    WHERE C2.seatNumber = C1.seatNumber AND C2.dateOut > C1.dateOut);
```

which should not get mangled by Access.

If you've ever seen the movie *The Producers* there's a courtroom scene at the end that has Zero Mostel's character saying to Gene Wilder's "Leo!  Don't help me!"  I find myself saying the same thing frequently when using MS Office.

Comment: Thanks Larry, I was trying to avoid having to create a separate query for no other reason than I do like everything to be neat and more queries just seems messy to me. I should probably let go of this particular compulsion but hey, we all have our quirks. Thank you for the rework, it works great. Now I'm off to pull it all apart so I can figure out how it works.  Oh and if I could get MS Office not to help me all the time, I'd be right. I haven't seen the movie, but I feel it.

Comment: I hear you, but consider that if you use the same internal table logic elsewhere in the application then you're violating DRY principles and might want to consider using an intermediate view.

Comment: Just a variation (subjectively more readable) of Larry's proposal:

SELECT * FROM Checkout as C1
WHERE C1.dateOut = (SELECT MAX(dateOut) FROM Checkout as C2 
                    WHERE C2.seatNumber = C1.seatNumber)

Answer (score 0):

I fired up Access and ran the following query in Access 2010 against a copy of Northwind.mdb, and it didn't get auto-corrected. What version of Access are you on?

```
SELECT orders.*
from orders, (select orderid, max(quantity) as maxq from [order details] group by orderid ) as results
where orders.orderid = results.orderid
```

Comment: I'm using 2003 and it only mangles it when I go to open the query from the menu, if I run it from the actual query, it works fine, which is how I knew that it actually worked in the first place.  If I don't run it from the menu, I can use the query table fine in other areas such as VBA.